# MySQL select inside select where text field is not empty

Tags: mysql

Please, how can I make this query work?

I already try D.descricao <> '' / D.descricao IS NOT NULL / ORDER BY LENGTH(descricao) DESC LIMIT 1 and nothing.

The Join of tables produtos and cluster8 return a number X of rows. In this rows some has the column descricao with some content and others are empty. With the subquery (line 2) I'm trying to get a record where descricao is not empty, but not sucessful until now.

And the reason I used the subquery is because when all rows has descricao = empty, even so will return the other fields in the main SELECT.

Here's the SQLfiddle: [sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2806a/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2806a/1)

```
SELECT P.loja_id, 
       P.categoria_id, 
       C.centroide_produto_id, 
       (SELECT D.descricao 
        FROM   produtos D 
        WHERE  D.produto_id = C.centroide_produto_id 
               AND D.descricao <> '' 
        ORDER  BY Length(descricao) DESC) AS descricao 
FROM   produtos P, 
       cluster8 C 
WHERE  P.produto_id = C.centroide_produto_id 
       AND C.centroide_produto_id = 1926 
GROUP  BY centroide_produto_id
```

Comment: provide your table structures, sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to `group by`, then you need to use aggregate functions, such as `sum`, `min`, `max`... on all the fields which you select that aren't in the `group by` list. Also, I would suggest using an `inner join` instead of your 2nd `select`. Then you will only need a single `where` clause. You might need a `having` clause depending on your intentions and on which aggregate functions you choose.

**Edit:**

The following will not produce matching `produto_id`, `nome` and `descricao`, but it looks like that is what you wanted, based on your sqlfiddle. Also, it seems like you should be able to replace the whole `ORDER BY` clause with a `max()` on `D.descricao` in the select list, but you can tweak those things.

```
SELECT P.produto_id, 
       P.nome, 
       D.descricao
FROM   produtos P, 
       cluster8 C,
       produtos D
WHERE  P.produto_id = C.centroide_produto_id 
       AND C.centroide_produto_id = 10 
       AND D.produto_id = C.similar_produto_id 
       AND D.descricao <> ''
GROUP  BY centroide_produto_id, P.nome -- <-- added P.nome here
ORDER  BY Length(D.descricao) DESC
```

Comment: Hi there! The reason I not used the join is because when all rows has descricao = empty, will not return any row. That's why I need to use this subquery..

Comment: OK. I think I see what you're saying. My Portuguese isn't as good as my Spanish or English, but it looks like your cluster8 table is one-to-many with your produtos table, is that right? I really wonder about your table structure though, because it sounds like you have store ID and product category ID in the product ("many") table, and then product ID, in both tables. It doesn't sound normalized to me, because you are joining the produtos table on either side of the cluster8 table, on the same primary key. Are you convinced that it is? Can you explain that?

Comment: Try the code in my edit above. What problems or errors do you get. Is it progress?

Comment: Hi Kent! produtos table has the product information: name, link, image, description (descricao) /// cluster8 table is where I join the similar products (clustering) /// I use this query in a page detail product showing the name, image, description. After the products are clustered, I will list the similar products in this page (like a price comparison site), and I need retrieve only a description information once they are all the same. But some has description (produtos table) and other not. That's why the reason of this query.

Comment: Didn't work in what way, an error or incorrect results? What error?

Comment: Ops! I need the descricao column is not null

Comment: Ok, I changed the edit part of my answer. The results of the query match what it sounds like you want.

Comment: Gret logic! Was exactly what I need! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you can just join them

```
SELECT P.loja_id, 
       P.categoria_id, 
       C.centroide_produto_id
FROM   cluster8 C 
JOIN  produtos P
        on C.centroide_produto_id = P.produto_id
WHERE  P.produto_id = C.centroide_produto_id 
       AND C.centroide_produto_id = 1926 
       AND P.descricao <> ''
       AND P.descricao is not null 
GROUP  BY C.centroide_produto_id
```

Comment: Hi there! The reason I not used the join is because when all rows has descricao = empty, will not return any row. That's why I need to use this subquery..